# NetBeans GUI Builder from existing file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, netbeans-12

I am new to NetBeans IDE and I am using NetBeans GUI builder for creating my GUIs. I am creating a new file by right-clicking the package and click new and then click the new JFrame Form.

It is working fine. But I have a java file with a JFrame which I created manually by coding.

Can I import it into that GUI builder so that I can drag and drop and make the GUI? If yes How can I do that? (In eclipse we can do that by right-clicking the file and click open with windowbuilder editor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Netbeans GUI builder works by generating code fully controlled by Netbeans, plus it maintains a hidden `.form` file. So you can't *directly* import your `JFrame` and make it fully customizable by the GUI Builder.

However there are things that might help.

You can modify your `JFrame` by adding `JPanels` designed using the GUI Builder. In Netbeans project view, select your package and create a new **JPanel form**, edit it, save it. Then in your `JFrame` code, manually insert `JPanel` instances where you need it.

Another trick:

- Extract the UI code from your `JFrame` and create a `JPanel` file with
  it, with a public no-argument constructor.
- Compile it
- Select the JPanel file in the Netbeans projet view, then righ-click **Tools/Add to palette**
- Add it to a Category (you can create your own category if needed)
- Create a new **JFrame form** from Netbeans
- You should see your `JPanel` component available in the GUI builder palette, in the relevant Category
- Drag & drop your `JPanel` component in the `JFrame` form

Note that the JPanel will not be editable itself, you can just manipulate it as a block in the GUI builder.

NOTE: in my experience, after doing **Tools/Add to palette**, it's sometimes needed to close/reload a form file to have the added component actually appear in the GUI builder palette.

Comment: Sir thanks  it helped. If Possibile can you explain some more.(If only possible).?

Comment: What do you not understand?